# 'pip install pyeto' gives version and distribution error

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm trying to install a package called pyeto. Their website (https://pyeto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) does not mention any problems regarding the installation and I can't find any installation related problems of other users. I'm doubting what solution I should look for (I would appreciate it to not have to reinstall python). I'm running python version 3.6.8 and the errors are presented below.

If you have an idea on how to solve this issue please let me know. I'm not an expert on how python runs in the background and how packages are installed through pip. Thanks in advance! B.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyeto (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyeto
```

EDIT: pip --version

```
pip 20.2.2 from c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.6)
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: Interestingly I have the same error on pip 20.2.2

Comment: Perhaps pyeto only supports Python 2?

Comment: According to their github page versions 2.7, 3.4 - 3.8, PyPy and PyPy3 should work. But I will check if I can use an older version of python to install the package

Comment: Apparently the author hasn't put it on pypi.  See https://github.com/woodcrafty/PyETo/issues/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author hasn't put it on pypi, so pip is treating it as an unknown package.

See https://github.com/woodcrafty/PyETo/issues/3

Answer (score -1):

Check on the website on what version it is supported.